# how to order by month name chronologically instead of alphabetically?

Tags: mysql, sql, spagobi

I would like to get the month names to be in chronological order instead of alphabetically ordered. Here is my Sql code.

```
select  SUM(montant_ht)as Achat ,monthname(dim_date.date) as mois 
from operation_odoo  
join dim_date on operation_odoo.id_date_facturation = dim_date.id_date
where (operation_odoo.id_type_op=1) and (dim_date.Annee= ? or ? is null )
group by mois
```

Comment: Simply use the column in your calendar table with the month number in it, add it to Group By and then Order By it.

Comment: On a sidenote: Are you sure you want to group by month alone regardless of the year?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can order by the month.  I would recommend:

```
order by month(max(dim_date.date))
```

As for your query, I would propose:

```
select monthname(d.date) as mois,
       sum(o.montant_ht)as Achat 
from operation_odoo o join
     dim_date d
     on o.id_date_facturation = d.id_date
where o.id_type_op = 1 and
      ( d.Annee= ? or ? is null )
group by mois
order by month(max(d.date));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use order by month()

```
    select  
        SUM(montant_ht)as Achat 
    ,monthname(dim_date.date) as mois 
    from operation_odoo  
    join dim_date on operation_odoo.id_date_facturation = dim_date.id_date
    where (operation_odoo.id_type_op=1) and (dim_date.Annee= ? or ? is null )
    group by mois
    order by month(dim_date.date)
```

for the SpagoBI try add also the column month()  to the query

```
select  
    SUM(montant_ht)as Achat 
,monthname(dim_date.date) as mois 
,  month(dim_date.date)
from operation_odoo  
join dim_date on operation_odoo.id_date_facturation = dim_date.id_date
where (operation_odoo.id_type_op=1) and (dim_date.Annee= ? or ? is null )
group by mois,  month(dim_date.date)
order by month(dim_date.date)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but it shows the correct result in phpMyAdmin but in my SpagoBI report it shows by  the alphabetic order . I don't know why any idea for help please ?

Answer (score 0):

in select query include additional column for month number and order by month number
make sure you include same in group by as well

Sample Query :

```
select current_Date,DATE_FORMAT(current_date,'%b') as 
m_name,DATE_FORMAT(current_date,'%m') as m_num
order by m_num
```